# Where is the starting point of the TO THE RESCUE - Choopeka mission?

Tags: the-hunter-call-of-the-wild

The mission is given without a single clue about where to start looking for.

Are they coordinates to where we can find the trail to the missing person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googleing around I found this link:
[Answer](https://steamcommunity.com/app/518790/discussions/0/133258092245466059/)

But then I went to a place near by and found the start of the trail here:
[image: 8000 : 4789]